# Spring OAuth2 Persistent Token Store

Tags: spring, rest, access-token, oauth-2.0

> Hi, I was reviewing an article and was wondering if this is enough to use as a persistent token store in Spring (server restarts). The only thing necessary is the signing key to validate token issued, correct?

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Thanks.

John